# How to have a custom contacts list in Android

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-contacts

This is my first application in Android. I am trying to maintain a list of contacts (a subset of the phone contacts) in my own application. I was to an extent read the contacts from Android and try to manipulate with it. But the challenge I face is,

- Storing the contacts (persisting) in the application preferably through Preferences. (ListPreference not usable for this).
- I only need name, phone number and email from every contact and display it in a list view.

The equivalent iPhone version looks like this. But how to close achieve this in Android

[image]

Any tips on achieving the above is much appreciated.

Comment: I do hope that's not a real phone number you're showing there.

Comment: @AakashM: ofcourse not !

Comment: I'd use SQLite. Don't make it fancy. Just a quick database adapter and an open helper. Then tailor an Insert, a Query, and a Delete to your needs. (You can do a delete and insert in your code for Update.)

Comment: Just a funny suggestion.. Let Android stuff look like Android.. Don't create IPhone lookalikes ...

Comment: @AlokKulkarni : obviously not. android does have contacts section, i want that layout here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a subset of the phone contacts why don't you store in a SQLite table just the lookup-URI of the contacts you want to have in your subset? You can store both the contact lookup-URI and ID if you are worried about the performances of lookup-uri.